# Log network drops

Tags: windows-7, network-monitoring

Is there way to list/log network disconnections on Win7?

I'm getting re-connected many times a day to interenet and it havent been happening just few weeks ago. So I want to have these drops listed so I can show them to my internet provider.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel | administrative Tools | Computer management

```
Computer management
   + System Tools
       + Task scheduler
       + Event Viewer
            + Custom Views
            + Windows Logs
                 - Application
                 - Security
                 - Setup
                 - System <----
                 - Forwarded Event
            + Applications and Services
    ...
```

Look for event ID = 27, source = your network card drive, e.g. for Intel gigabit ethernet, "e1yexpress". Just filter it and copy/paste.

[image]

Comment: May I ask how can select all filtered events? I tried but it seems it can be only saved single event and save it in csv format

Answer (score 2):

I would use either [Performance Ping](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/perfping.html)  or  , if you have access to a machine on their network, such as a SSH shell account, you might be able to use [Java Net Perf](http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php) to get much more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Check your router, it may well log these events

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 27 is pretty large if you don't know the name for source.  You can check for Event ID# 10400, Source = NDIS.

The other way that I found will work...disconnect the wire/wireless and then re-enable.  Check the event viewer immediately and you'll see the events related to the disconnect.  Get those event ids and source to help further troubleshoot.