# How can document bad internet performance frequency over certain time period?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ping, event-log, event-viewer

Recently, due to bad quality of internet in my new flat, I tried to figure out to document **internet-drops logs** over a certain period of time (not asking about when a connection is made or lost, but when there are any issues with the connection) and report it to management. I have tried the following methods unsuccessfully:

- Using Windows `Event Viewer`: to filter interested `Event ID` logs and export all Events in `.csv` file based on this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/225228/log-network-drops) unsuccessfully because of not being able to select all events in this environment.

  `Run --> eventvwr.msc`
- Using freaking `ping`: to select interesting events manually. Despite lots of tools, currently, I'm using some ping-based tools like [ALSEDI pinger](http://alsedi.com/pinger.php) as follows:
  [image: img]

and web-based tools like [TestMy.Net](https://testmy.net/auto) for multiple attempts. Additionally, even web-based [dslreports.com](http://www.dslreports.com/), open source [ones](https://www.snapfiles.com/downloadfind.php?action=s&ref=2&st=ping%20tool), like [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) and [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) or [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html.).

Any inputs or guidance, particularly regarding the second scenario, will be appreciated.

**Edit:** Following is the Ethernet set-up to access to the internet in my place:
[image: img]

Comment: What type of Internet connection does your new flat have or is it just an "Ethernet port in the wall"?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your reply. I just updated the question concerning my Internet structure in our flat using modem router supplied by the port in the wall via a coaxial cable.

Comment: First ping based tools are not ideal as you don't know if ICMP packets are not priorized. Second i would search for tools that record availability of one ore more web site. Such tools are usually developed for 24/7 surveillance. Use a tools that performs real web requests.